# Dictionaries lookup times

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to use dictionaries to index web pages for my crawlers, and I'm running into some interesting and memory problems.

I'm creating a dictionary for an index (format: keyword:[url1, url2, url3, ...]), which I will use to keep track of what pages contain what words. When I gather web pages, I use the function add_page_to_index()

```
def add_page_to_index(self, url):
    for keyword in url.get_text().split():
        self.add_to_index(keyword, url)
def add_to_index(self, keyword, url):
    for word in self.index:
        if word == keyword:
            if url not in self.index[word]:
                self.index[word].append(url)
            return
    # not found, add new keyword to index
    self.index[keyword] = [url]
```

This code has served me rather well (I know it has performance issues, but efficiency is not of the essence for this project), but when I change add_to_index() to this:

```
def add_to_index(self, keyword, url):
    if keyword in self.index:
        self.index[keyword].append(url)
    else: # not found, add new keyword to index
        self.index[keyword] = [url]
```

suddenly python's memory usage skyrockets (I eventually get a MemoryError). Is this a problem with my code or is there another explanation?

Note that I'm a high schooler, so I don't necessarily have the most expansive programming background.

Thanks!

EDIT: changed it to my original.

Comment: Strange - `index = {}` before `word in index` will guarantee nothing gets done. Did you mean to have that line somewhere outside of the `add_to_index` function, as a global variable?

Comment: In both cases the `add_to_index` creates a new dictionary and then discards it. What is the point of this function?

Comment: Where does `word` come from in you second code section?

Comment: Sorry this is part of a bigger class, I will edit to the more original ones

Comment: @hisroar: Can you just post all of your code at once?

Comment: Actually is it necessary? The formatting gets messed up (indents) and it's part of my ongoing research

Comment: Your new version does not contain a check if the list already contains the url - have you checked that the memory increase is not because of duplicates? Also, if you don't want to have duplicates, just use a set to store the urls instead of a list.

Comment: Darn, you're right. I'll look into it

Comment: @l4mpi you were right about the duplicates (I reached recursion depth when using a recursive sort...) but the memory was still wonky even though I used sets, still at absurd numbers (I got ~15 minutes worth of data, and the memory usage was twice the usage of ~60 minutes of data using the original). Regardless, I'm going to be using the first one (makes my life easier ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit might be the absence of `for word in self.index` and `if url not in self.index[keyword]` in the second case. Without it:

- memory might be consumed by duplicates in `self.index[keyword]`
- the code is faster so the memory also grows faster because more data is processed

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def __init__(self, ...):
    self.index = defaultdict(set)
    # ...

def add_page_to_index(self, page):
    for keyword in page.get_text().split():
        self.add_to_index(keyword, page)

def add_to_index(self, keyword, page):
    self.index[keyword].add(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key difference between your two sets of code is the following line, which appears in the memory hog only:

```
if keyword in self.index:
```

My guess in this case is that `self.index` is quite large, and having to check through `self.index` every time the method is called is what's killing you.

You should also look into if you necessarily need to have all of the data that you're collecting stored in the interpreter memory at once.  You're probably best off storing as much of the data as you can in some kind of more permanent structure, like a csv, or redis, or something like that.

Comment: `self.index` is a dict so `keyword in self.index` is O(1) amortized.